# Estimating how much two probability distributions differ

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, matlab, average

I have two probability distributions A and B.

First I would like to estimate how much they differ.
In this regard I use as metric the Jensen–Shannon distance (i.e. the square root of Jensen–Shannon divergence).

This metric is bounded between 0 and 1.

If the probability distributions differ less than 10% (i.e. d<0.1) I would like to create a "super probability distribution" that ensemble the two. Is there a way to do that? I guess that averaging the 2 probability distributions is not the right choice...

EDIT:
Plase consider the case of having 3 (or more) probability distributions A B C with the respective pairwise distances (ab,ac,bc) all < 0.1 and that the resulting "super probability" should tend to the average of the probabilities that differ less...

Comment: In a sense averaging or [mixing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) the two distributions is not the worst option.  It is equivalent to saying "toss a coin: if it is heads, take a value from $A$, and if tails take a value from $B$".

Comment: @Henry thanks! I edited the question with a more general (different) case...Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Again, a mixture distribution equivalent to choosing one of the three or more underlying distributions at random and selecting from that is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution without mixing is to use averaging of parameters. For instance, if you have several normal distributions with means $\mu_1,\mu_2,...$ and standard deviations $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...$, you can calculate the average out of them and use $\bar{\mu}$ and $\bar{\sigma}$ for the super-distribution.

Another possibility is to calculate average of cumulative density functions.

Note that both approaches coincide with mixing for discrete sets where the probability mass functions are practically real vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My initial probability distributions are dirichlet distributions composed by 12 elements.